# hadoop2.2.0 installation on linux ( NameNode not starting )

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to run a single node hadoop cluster on my machine with the following config:

```
inux livingstream 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am able to format the namenode without any problems however when I try and start the namenode using :

```
hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

I get the following errors :

```
ishan@livingstream:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/ishan': Permission denied
chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/ishan': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/ishan/hadoop-ishan-namenode-livingstream.out
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 138: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-ishan-namenode.pid: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /var/log/hadoop/ishan/hadoop-ishan-namenode-livingstream.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/ishan/hadoop-ishan-namenode-livingstream.out' for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /var/log/hadoop/ishan/hadoop-ishan-namenode-livingstream.out: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /var/log/hadoop/ishan/hadoop-ishan-namenode-livingstream.out: No such file or directory
```

I did not create a separate user "hduser" for hadoop installation. I am using my exsisting username. May be that is why I am facing the problem.
Can someone please help me with this .

Exactly what permissions do I need to alter to get this working ?

**UPDATE**
After fiddling around and getting around the permission problems I have moved on to new stupidity of errors posted here : [hadoop Nanenode wont start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974096/hadooop-nanenode-wont-start)
I will forever keep you guys in mind if you can nudge me in the right direction so that I can start some real work on this.

Comment: The listed directories should be owned by the application user. In your case it should be owned by the existing user that you are using. The easiest is to create the directory /var/log/hadoop and /var/run/hadoop and make it owned by your existing user.

Comment: @alvits : I was afaraid thats the case , owner of /var/* is "root" is there any way I can change the HADOOP_LOG_DIR ?

Comment: You will have to modify the scripts and several config files. Are you willing to go that route? Don't you have root or sudo access? Because modifying the config will also require root access in the first place.

Comment: @alvits I have root access ,now when I start the namenode and datanode using sudo , it doesnt throw any error but "jps" shows nothing and http://localhost:50070/ is unable to connect.
So I dont think Sudo workds as well.
I have updated the question

Comment: It seems you haven't configured the namenode yet. The process didn't find the required host/port. This is where you'll define the hostname and the port 50070.

Comment: @alvits : may be , Also the idea of creating the required directories and chaging permission wont work each time , Ill have to do it over and over when I start or stop the namenodes.
I will have a look at all my config files again. :)

Comment: It is correct to start/stop using sudo or root. The script will setuid to the configured process owner. However do check that you have the correct configuration, specifically, the process owner (hadoop owner), the listening address and port and the new parameter corresponding to the now deprecated HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: @alvits : can you point me to those configuration files please.
I did the installation again with the hduser and i get same errors with different file location this time /var/run .. I am little confused as to why would it create log file in a location accessible only by root ???

Comment: The default configuration directories are in /etc/<service>/conf. So for hadoop it will be in /etc/hadoop/conf and for hbase it will be in /etc/hbase/conf. The log directories are placed in the usual location as system logs. This is not unusual as services start with escalated privilege and then drops to application owners. You should also check /etc/alternatives in case your system uses alternatives.

Comment: @alvits I have checked and rechecked my configurations , I got around the permission errors as well. But I am still getting that host port authority error :(