# hadoop Nanenode wont start

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

if you are visiting this link through my previous question : [hadoop2.2.0 installation on linux ( NameNode not starting )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877293/hadoop2-2-0-installation-on-linux-namenode-not-starting)

you probably know! I have been  trying to run single-node mode for hadoop-2.2.0 for a long time now :D 
if not visit that and ull find out :)

finally, after following the tutorials I can format the namenode fine , however when I start the namenode I see the following error in the logs:

```
2014-05-31 15:44:20,587 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
```

I have googled for the solution , most of them asks to check double check and keep checking **core-site.xml , mapred-site.xml , hdfs-site.xml**  I have done all those and they look absolutely fine to me. Does any one have any clues as to what might be going wrong?

**UPDATE**
location of the files  **/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop**

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration
```

Comment: Could you please show me these files?

Comment: @Tariq : I updated the question with the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`file://`**, so that values look like this for absolute paths with a URI schema:

```
file:///usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode
file:///usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode
```

Change the values of **dfs.namenode.name.dir** and **dfs.datanode.data.dir** properties, accordingly. Format the NameNode properly and start the daemons. Also, make sure you have proper ownership and permissions on these directories.

Comment: thanks ! I had one more question , When I get a handle fs = FileSystem.get(conf) and print the fs.gethomeDirectory() shoudlnt it be the path to my hdfs? it prints out /home/myname my localfile system

Comment: only when I add this line to my conf its gets the correct path **conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://localhost:54310");**
so I am assuming configuration takes local systems configuration by defeautl?

Comment: Because the configuration files should be in your CLASSPATH. If these files are not present in the CLASSPATH, you have to add them manually in your code by specifying their path. Get basically returns the configured filesystem implementation, which defaults to the local FS, if these config files are unavailable.